# Qual o sujeito da frase "Parece que você cometeu um erro"?

Tags: gramática, sujeito, sujeito-indeterminado

Estou interessado em encontrar o sujeito da frase

> Parece que você cometeu um erro.

Me parece que o sujeito dessa frase é inexistente ou indeterminado, única e exclusivamente, porque sei  (por motivos de vivência) que a tradução dessa frase para o inglês é

> It seems that you made a mistake.

O fato de existir **it** na frase acima me indica que o sujeito (do verbo parecer) não está na sentença.

Porém quando eu "faço a pergunta para o verbo":

> **Frase:** Parece que você cometeu um erro.
>
> **Pergunta:** Quem ou o que parece?
>
> **Resposta:** você

como a reposta aparenta ser **você** isso implicaria que a palavra **você** é o sujeito da oração. Alguém poderia me explicar o que eu estou confundindo?

Só para deixar claro, tenho total ciência que traduzir a frase e analizar em outra lingua o que está acontecendo não faz muito sentido. Apenas utilizei desse recurso para tentar encontrar um "candidato a sujeito da frase".

Comment: Isto é mais complexo do que me pareceu à primeira vista. Mas parece-me seguro que *você* não é o sujeito. Repara: "**Parece** que vocês cometeram um erro" e não "**Parecem** que vocês cometeram um erro". Ora *vocês* não pode ser sujeito de *parece*, e as duas frases têm a mesma estrutura. Eu pensei que fosse impessoal, mas não encontrei gramática nenhuma que inclua *parecer* nos verbos impessoais. Encontrei uns sites que dizem que o sujeito de *parece* é a oração subordinada "que você cometeu um erro". À laia de "consta que você cometeu um erro".

Comment: Sua resposta me convenceu que **você** não pode ser sujeito, esse seu truque de trocar a pessoa  da frase é bem boa. Obrigado!

Comment: Isto foi só um comentário. Não estou seguro o suficiente para dar uma resposta. Mas agora reparei numa frase no meu próprio comentário: "Mas parece-me seguro que *você* não é o sujeito." Repara, aqui, "que você não é o sujeito" é o sujeito de *parece* -- "Mas isso parece-me seguro", em que "isso" = "que *você* não é o sujeito"; Mas na tua frase, se a analisarmos do mesmo modo, não há predicativo nenhum; ficava só, "Isso parece" ("isso" = que você cometeu um erro". A menos que admitamos que há um "verdade" implícito: "Parece verdade que você cometeu um erro" -- "Isso parece verdade".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decididamente, *você* não é sujeito desse *parece*. Vejamos:

> Parece *que você cometeu um erro*
> Parece *que vocês cometeram um erro*
> Parece *que nós cometemos um erro*

O verbo *parecer* continua na terceira pessoa do singular quando trocamos *você* por *vocês* ou *nós*, em vez de passar a *parecem* e *parecemos*. Logo, *você, vocês* e *nós* são apenas os sujeitos das orações subordinadas a itálico (o verbo *cometer* concorda sempre com eles) mas não da subordinante, que fica sempre *parece*.

Agora, acerca do sujeito do*parece* não há consenso entre os gramáticos. O [Ciberdúvidas tem até um artigo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/parece-me-que--complemento-direto-ou-sujeito/2444) apontando as duas posições. A posição dominante é que o sujeito é a oração subordinada (em itálico), mas há quem defenda que este *parecer* é impessoal, e que a oração subordinada é antes um complemento direto. Comecemos pela última. [José Neves Henriques no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/regencia-de-parecer--analise-sintactica/8979) apresenta o seguinte exemplo (formatação minha, com a oração subordinante em letra normal e a subordinada em itálico, tal como acima):

> Parecia *que as certezas eram incertas*

Diz ele que o verbo *parecer* é aqui impessoal, portanto sem sujeito. [Sandra Tavares (Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/parece-me--complemento-direto/2443) acrescenta que nos seguintes exemplos a oração subordinada é complemento direto do verbo *parecer*:

> Parece *que estes homens são magnatas*
> Parece-me *que estou ouvindo S. Mateus*

Comparemos com um exemplo incontroverso: em “eu vi *que elas chegaram*”, a oração subordinada é complemento direto de “vi”; é como “eu vi isso”, em que “isso” = “que elas chegaram”. Mas [Vergílio Dias (Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/a-inaceitavel-hipotese-transitiva-do-verbo-parecer/2446) afirma que *parecer* não admite complemento direto, e que a oração subordinada é sujeito do verbo *parecer*.

Vejamos antes um exemplo incontroverso: em “consta do relatório *que elas chegaram*”, “*que elas chegaram*” é sujeito do verbo *constar* (“*isso* consta do relatório”)

[Regina Rocha (Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/parece-me--sujeito-oracional/2445) também diz a oração subordinada é sujeito de *parecer*, e cita vários gramáticos consagrados que têm também essa posição. Eis os exemplos deles (todos dizem que a oração subordinada, em itálico, é o sujeito do verbo *parecer*):

> Parece *que tudo vai bem* (Evanildo Bechara, *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa*, 2003)
>
> Parece *que vamos ter um belo dia de sol […]* (Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra, *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, 1984)
>
> Não vos parece *que é terrivel cousa ser a morte momentânea?* (Epifânio da Silva Dias, *Syntaxe Historica Portuguesa*, 1916).

Esta abordagem causou-me alguma estranheza. Numa frase como “João parece contente” temos sujeito (“João”) e predicativo do sujeito (“contente”). Portanto eu esperaria que *parecer* tivesse sempre um predicativo do sujeito. Mas nestas frases com *parece* + oração subordinada, se a oração subordinada é o sujeito de *parece*, então fica simplesmente “isso parece” (em que “isso” é por exemplo “que tudo vai bem”). Mas então isso parece o quê? era a minha interrogação. Uma solução é reinterpretar *parecer* nesta nestas frases. Eis o que diz [Regina Rocha](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/parece-me--sujeito-oracional/2445) a propósito de “Parece-me *que estou ouvindo S. Mateus*”:

> O verbo **parecer** não é classificado como verbo impessoal (como, por exemplo, o verbo **haver** ou o verbo **chover**), pelo que não se pode considerar a existência de um sujeito nulo expletivo, havendo necessidade de se conceber um sujeito. E o sujeito está lá: *estar a ouvir S. Mateus* afigura-se-lhe, surge como algo que parece ser verdade. Aliás, o verbo **parecer** no sentido de «afigurar-se-lhe», «surgir como uma hipótese verdadeira aos olhos de alguém», «ser (algo) verosímil», «ser (algo) provável» (que é o significado com que surge na frase apresentada) tem subentendido um predicativo do sujeito: «estar a ouvir S. Mateus parece *verdade», «parece-me verdade (certo, real) que estou ouvindo S. Mateus», «isso parece verdadeiro», «isso parece real».

Answer (score 4):

Hoje em dia, a posição mais comum parece ser considerar que o argumento de *parecer* não tem estatuto de sujeito. Por exemplo, no *Áreas Críticas da Língua Portuguesa* de João Andrade Peres e Telmo Móia, consideram que as frases

> (a) Parece que os miúdos gostam da professora.
>   (b) Os miúdos parecem gostar da professora.

têm a mesma estrutura subjacente

> (a') [] PARECER [que os miúdos gostam da professora]
>   (b') [] PARECER [os miúdos gostar da professora]

(e em (b) segue-se um movimento de elevação de *miúdos* para a posição vazia de sujeito da frase matriz). Citando:

> Repare-se que estamos a postular a existência de um elemento vazio na posição de sujeito da frase matriz em ambas as estruturas. Quer isto dizer que consideramos que o verbo *parecer* tem um único argumento, que não recebe o estatuto de sujeito. Trata-se de uma análise possível, que encontra plena justificação dentro de certos quadros teóricos que aqui não podemos apresentar. No entanto, para que o leitor possa aderir intuitivamente à análise, achamos útil chamar-lhe a atenção para o facto de, em certas línguas como o francês e o inglês, aquela posição vir preenchida com um elemento de tipo pronominal sem conteúdo semântico — por isso designado **pronome expletivo** [...]. Aliás, em certas variantes do português podemos encontrar uma frase como (870).
>
> (868) *Il* semble que les enfants aiment leur institutrice.
>   (869) *It* seems that the children like their teacher.
>   (870) *Ele* parece que os miúdos gostam da professora.

Um argumento para que a posição de sujeito esteja vazia em *parecer* é o facto de que, tal como *chover* ou *haver* (no sentido de existir ou temporal), *parecer* não se pode combinar com o *se* nominativo (impessoal) na frase matriz:

> Na literatura produzida no âmbito da Gramática Generativa, tem-se considerado que o clítico impessoal está associado à posição de Sujeito e absorve o caso nominativo, razão pela qual é designado por “se nominativo”.

citando a tese de mestrado de [Afonso João Miguel](http://www.clul.ulisboa.pt/files/telmo_moia/afonsomiguel2006.pdf). Os exemplos aí dados são:

> a. *Este Inverno, choveu-se pouco em Portugal.
>    b. *Há-se de tudo um pouco, na loja da esquina.
>    c. *Parece-se estar bom tempo.

Comment: Muito interessante sua reposta. Obrigado!

Comment: @MatheusManzatto adicionei mais qualquer coisinha.

Comment: Intuitivamente para mim, no exemplo (a), é também o PARECER impessoal que faz mais sentido. Mas que significa a "elevação do sujeito no (b)? Aí, PARECER concorda com *miúdos*. Então não é mesmo o sujeito? (Ao contrário de "os miúdos parece que gostam da professora".)

Comment: @Jacinto sim, é sujeito é na estrutura de superfície. A teoria é que _parecer_ seleciona apenas um argumento único (oração finita, oração infinitiva, ou oração reduzida como em `[] PARECER [os miúdos contentes]`), cujo sujeito se pode (ou tem de) mover para a posição vazia de sujeito, numa estrutura de elevação (ou _alçamento_, em PB). Já na gramática tradicional, faz mais sentido, ainda que seja discutível, falar de _que os miúdos gostam da professora_ como um sujeito de parecer. Tens [aqui](http://www.filologia.org.br/ixcnlf/15/18.htm) vários exemplos de elevações.

Comment: "os miúdos contentes" é uma oração? E em "Parece impossível que ele tenha dito isso!" Aqui já me parece natural interpretar "que ele tenha dito isso" como sujeito.

Comment: @Jacinto Bom, para o conceito de "oração" no [_Áreas Críticas_](http://artefacto-test.s3.amazonaws.com/%C3%81reas%20Cr%C3%ADticas%20da%20L%C3%ADngua%20Portuguesa.pdf) (pág. 81), que inclui a oração pequena. Em "Parece impossível que ele tenha dito isso!" de facto _que ele tenha dito isso_ parece ser sujeito (= _isso parece impossível_) na estrutura de superfície. Mas em todo o caso, _parecer_ seleciona  apenas uma oração como argumento; _que ele tenha dito isso_ é argumento de _impossível_, não de _parecer_. (continua)

Comment: Compara com _Acho/É impossível que ele tenha dito isso_, onde _impossível_ é predicativo do sujeito (com _ser_) ou do complemento direto (com _achar_), sendo o sujeito/complemento directo (respectivamente) _que ele tenha dito isso_.