# Por que o sujeito de frases como "Está chovendo", "Chove lá fora" e "Está nevando" é inexistente?

Tags: semântica, sujeito

Nunca entendi o porquê disso. Pra mim sempre foi um caso de sujeito oculto.

O sujeito de "Está chovendo" é a chuva, pois é ela quem chove. Analogamente o de "Chove lá fora" é a chuva e o de "Está nevando" é a neve.

É redundante, sim, mas não quer dizer que seja errado só por ser redundante.

Estou muito errado em pensar assim? Por quê?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em muitos casos a aplicação dessas classificações tem algum grau de subjetividade, e não é incomum haver divergências inclusive entre especialistas. Então sua posição talvez não seja *errada*, mas apenas incomum.

Por exemplo, um caso bem interessante, relacionado à pergunta, é o da "[Qual o sujeito da frase "Parece que você cometeu um erro"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5647/2764)", em que o sujeito pode ser visto como inexistente ou como sendo a frase que começa com "que" (caso em que "parecer" é implicitamente "parecer verosímil/verdade/provável/real").

De volta à questão:

> "Está chovendo", "Chove lá fora" e "Está nevando"

A justificativa usual para classificar esses exemplos como de sujeito inexistente é que neles não haveria um sujeito claro ou mesmo necessário. Numa frase com sujeito **subentendido** (antigamente chamado de sujeito oculto), ele é claro e necessário: "[eu] comi bolacha", "[nós] estamos perdidos"; no caso do sujeito **indeterminado**, ele é necessário, mas não claro: "comeram o bolo", "roubaram o carro". Enquanto em "está chovendo" ou "são duas horas" se considera que não cabe um sujeito, que ele não é nem necessário (é um fenômeno da natureza, apenas algo que acontece, uma situação), muito menos claro (a chuva chove, ou as nuvens chovem? ou o tempo chove, ou o céu..?): ou seja, que ele é **inexistente**.

Vale notar que mesmo em línguas como o francês ou o inglês, em que há um sujeito ("It's raining.") ele só está presente por força do rigor gramatical e é semanticamente vazio, sem significado, e não se refere a nada, a nenhum antecedente.

Isso obviamente não impede o uso figurado de verbos impessoais, [por exemplo](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf55.php):

> Amanheci mal-humorado. (Sujeito desinencial: eu)
> Choveram candidatos ao cargo. (Sujeito: candidatos)
> Fiz quinze anos ontem. (Sujeito desinencial: eu)

Também relevante: [Quando é que uma oração não tem sujeito?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/334/2764).

Comment: Uma curiosidade: em certos idiomas, a chuva (ou neve etc) é o sujeito. Por exemplo, em japonês:

雨が降っている
Ame ga futte imasu
Chuva está caindo (lit.)

Comment: Interessante, @kamekura . Em português, "a chuva cai/está caindo" também funciona, em japonês não há o equivalente a "está chovendo"?

Comment: no meu comentário acima,  "chuva está caindo" é simplesmente uma tradução literal para ilustrar a gramática japonesa (eu poderia ter usado uma glosa interlinear mas me pareceu desnecessário...). A tradução normal de "Ame ga futte imasu" seria simplesmente "Está chovendo". "A chuva cai" soa mais literário, né?

Comment: Que eu saiba, não há verbo em japonês coloquial que signifique "chover" (mas não ficaria surpreso se houvesse um termo usado me poesia etc). Mas sujeito subtendido é muito comum:
1. Ame ga futteimasen ne？ glosa: "chuva caindo não está (certo)?",  Não está chovendo, né?
2. Futte imasu yo. glosa: "caindo está (enfático)", Está chovendo sim.

Answer (score 0):

Sujeito inexistente não faz muito sentido neste caso,pois toda ação é realizada por algo,seja por uma força maior ou coisa do tipo. Esse "algo" é o sujeito e sem ele a ação não se realizaria. É uma questão de lógica.

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi a sua asserção final: «Mas quem somos nós [...]». Os membros da Academia Brasileira de Letras não regem nem a ortografia nem a gramática. Eles têm especialistas, como Evanildo Bechara, mas também tem escritores como Fernando Henrique Cardosos, Gilberto Gil e Fernanda Montenegro. Estes talvez entendam de gramática, mas não são vistos como especialistas. Ainda, a Academia de Letras de Portugal também não rege a gramática, outrossim. Obrigado pela contribuição e seja bem-vindo a fazer mais respostas!

Comment: Sim, me referia aos grandes mestres da gramática da língua portuguesa que compõe a cadeira. Mas obrigado por me lembrar deste detalhe.

Comment: @Schilive Salve! Comentario editado.

Comment: @portuglish Eu diria que, mais comum do que denotar "visto", o upvote no comentário pode denotar concordância.

Answer (score 0):

Se não tô enganado, e espero que não :P, há uma diferença entre sujeito oculto e indeterminado: o primeiro é da primeira e segunda pessoas enquanto o segundo da terceira pessoa (singular e plural), estando em ambos os casos elíptico. O sujeito inexistente é quando não há um ator do verbo, o que, me parece, é diferente do que disse o Stafusa. Vejamos: a chuva cai, mas ela não chove. Há uma diferença entre uma frase e outra. Acho que a confusão persiste no pensamento de reafirmação: "a chuva chove" é como "estou subindo pra cima". Então diríamos apenas "chove" (com algum complemento eventualmente), mas não a chuva chove. Do ponto de vista da palavra falada não há problema nenhum nas frases, já o da norma culta, acho que diverge disto.